# Is there a way to sign into multiple Gmail accounts with the mobile web interface when multiple sign in is enabled?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, mobile, google-multi-login

I have 2 different Google Apps accounts that are now full Google accounts plus a Gmail account. Because of this, I have multiple signin enabled. Because of this, I can only use 1 of the accounts at time in my mobile browser (Safari in this case) and I have to sign out and sign back in with another account.

Is there any way around this?

I must prefer the webmail vs the iPhone's Mail app for many reasons, but this could force me to use the Mail app more than I want to.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly helpful, but the Blackberry GMail app supports multiply logged in account.  I stay logged in on 4 different accounts.  Shift-J switches to the next account.  Usernames and passwords are remembered through restarts, but on a reinstall I have to re-enter all the information.